# Laravel 5/Composer terminal error: sh.exe": composer: command not found

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, laravel-5, composer-php

I get the error in the title when I try to run `composer require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"` in my terminal (Git Bash) under my current project file path. Even if I type something like `composer -v` I get the same error.

I've even tried reinstalling composer and it installs fine but the commands still don't work.

In the PhpSTORM terminal, running the same commands gives this error: `'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or bath file.`

I have VirtualBox, Vagrant and Laravel all installed correctly with Composer (I know it's all good because my code is great and works fine when trying it live and what not)... unless I'm missing something here (Laravel noob).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why I was getting the error: forgot to ssh.

The fix was this: `vagrant ssh` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed composer outside your virtual box (in your host system) and you want to use it without ssh into your vagrant box:

Make sure you add composers directory to your PATH. Then close your current terminal and reload a new one. Closing the terminal is necessary to reload the PATH.

The error `sh.exe": composer: command not found` indicates that the composer is not found in the current folder or the PATH.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge =)